# How to read from a 2-line text file and output each line to 2 variables in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hello in my program I need for a text file containing 2 lines to be read and each line's contents to be put into their own variable. the text file is called "account.txt" and is under the directory Documents. the code i have curently that sees if it exists is this:

```
        If File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "Account.txt")) Then
        MsgBox("Account found and is being loaded!")

    End If
```

I would like in that if statement for the file to be read and each line to be read and contents to be put into their own variable. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use a collection like `String()` or `List(Of String)` or read them with `File.ReadLines` or `File.ReadAllLines` and assign index 0 to variable 1 and index 1 to variable 2:

```
Dim path = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "Account.txt")
If File.Exists(path) Then
    Dim allLines = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    Dim line1 As String = allLines(0) ' indices are zero based 
    Dim line2 As String = allLines(1) 
End If
```

You can also use `ElementAtOrDefault(1)` instead of `allLines(1)` if you're not sure if the file contains two lines at all. It'l be `Nothing` if it contains less:

```
Dim line2 As String = allLines.ElementAtOrDefault(1) ' can be Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "Account.txt")) Then
    Dim accountReader As StreamReader = new StreamReader(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "Account.txt")
    Dim line1 As String = accountReader.ReadLine()
    Dim line2 As String = accountReader.ReadLine()
    reader.Close()
End If
```

This should work, have not tested it I usually work on C# so I tried to convert it to VB.Net I usually prefer to reader all lines into arrays and before assigned to it I do all necessary checks but this should get you started.

I seperated it like this since you mentioned that you want line contents into different variables.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for your time to look at my problem but sadly yours didnt work. :( however,, Tim Schmelter's fix did work. Again, thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Welcome, I haven't tested it since I am at work and tried to multitask helping someone else with their problems.